# How to add third party .NET dlls to Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, dll, jar

We have a requirement to add third party dll provided by payment gateway to our Xamarin Forms app. There is also a Jar file which wraps this dll. We need to include any one of this in our app. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to use an external library into you forms application you should bind the native library into you platform project.

Just as an example, talking about Android, you will have the third part library available as a jar.

So what you'll need to do is the following:

1 - Create a binding project 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-a-jar

2 - Consume your binded DLL (the one generated from you binding project) into your Xamarin.Android project (platform specific project inside your forms solution).

To follow this approach you need to be sure that the third part library is available both for Android and iOS (usually a jar for Android and a .a for iOS).

If you are lucky the library has already been binded to Xamarin.

Usually this is not the case, so you'll have to face funny days during the next weeks :D

Wish you good luck!!!

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. In my case, the library is gonna be xamarin binded for the first time. Interesting times ahead i guess. :(

Comment: BTW, one question i have is "can't this binded DLL be consumed in Xamarin Forms project(PCL)?"

Comment: Nope, the binded library can be used just in the platform specific project. If it was useful can you accept the answer? thanks

Comment: oh Thanks a lott... I would love to accept as answer but waiting for my 15 reputations..

Comment: Just like u said running into more trouble after binding the library.. it binded successfully and i am getting the methods and classes. When i invoke one method getting the below error.   "{Java.Lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: DLL NOT LOADEDCould not find JNA native support
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+StaticMethods.CallStaticBooleanMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method...."

Comment: maybe you just need to set the buildAction on the jar inside the binding project to InputJar, but not sure about this because every case it's different. If this doesn't work I suggest you to post a new question on StackOverflow ;)